# Impossible gap between tables in Outlook when using align in favor of float for an 'responsive' signature

Tags: outlook, alignment, margins

I'm having trouble with an 'responsive' email signature. It consists of two tables next to each other of which the right one moves underneath the left one when there is no room to sit next to each other.

After a lot of Outlook quirks, the only one that remains is a strange gap between the two tables, only visible in Outlook. I've read and researched many fixes and tricks provided here and by the likes of email on acid, Litmus, etc. but none really seem to work.

Included is the code I've settled with for now.

Any signature wizard who can help me with this conundrum?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style=" margin:0; padding:0; border:0; border-spacing:0;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="520" height="232" style="display:table;">
                <tr>
                <td width="260" height="232" style="vertical-align:top; align:left; display:table-cell;">
                <![endif]-->
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style=" width:260px!important; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; border-spacing:0;">
          <tr>
            <td height="232" width="200">
              <a href="http://www.stamix.be/nl" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://ibb.co/f9JGSH" width="260" height="232" border="0" alt="image 1" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:block; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;" />
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </td>
                <td style="width:260px; height:232px; vertical-align:top; align:left; display:table-cell;">
                <![endif]-->
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style=" width:260px!important; margin:0; padding:0; border-spacing:0;">
          <tr>
            <td height="232" width="200">
              <a href="http://www.stamix.be/nl" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://ibb.co/iWhbSH" width="260" height="232" border="0" alt="image 2" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:block; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;" />
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>    
                </td></tr></table>
                <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats with the empty lines?

Comment: The [tag:signature] tag is not for e-mail signatures.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in every version of Outlook and looks good in every email client I tested with using Litmus:

The biggest issue is inconsistency of code. Outlook sometimes ignores style sheets.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" align="left" style=" margin:0; padding:0; border:0; border-spacing:0;">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="520" height="232" style="display:table;">
          <tr>
            <td width="260" height="232" style="vertical-align:top; align:left; display:table-cell;">
        <![endif]-->
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style=" width:260px!important; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; border-spacing:0;">
            <tr>
                <td height="232" width="260">
                    <a href="http://www.stamix.be/nl" target="_blank">
                        <img src="https://ibb.co/f9JGSH" width="260" height="232" border="0" alt="image 1" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:block; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; background: red;" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </td>
            <td width="260" style="width:260px; height:232px; vertical-align:top; align:left; display:table-cell;">
        <![endif]-->
        <table width="260" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style=" width:260px!important; margin:0; padding:0; border-spacing:0;">
            <tr>
                <td height="232" width="260">
                    <a href="http://www.stamix.be/nl" target="_blank">
                        <img src="https://ibb.co/iWhbSH" width="260" height="232" border="0" alt="image 2" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:block; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; background: blue;" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>    

        </td></tr></table>

        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This also works. It doesn't stack, but you don't really explain why you need it to stack. So if you don't need stacking images, this is a far easier code to manipulate:

```
<table width="520" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
  <tr>
      <td width="260">
        <a href="http://www.stamix.be/nl" target="_blank"><img src="https://ibb.co/f9JGSH" width="260" height="232" border="0" alt="image 1" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:block; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; background: #ffff00;" /></a>
      </td>
      <td width="260">
        <a href="http://www.stamix.be/nl" target="_blank"><img src="https://ibb.co/iWhbSH" width="260" height="232" border="0" alt="image 2" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:block; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; background: #ff00ff;" /></a>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Good luck.